# Duplicate user accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users

I've found something strange on [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras)

[image]

This makes me think that this guy has created several accounts, each one has only asked a single question. He hasn't even upvoted or accepted an answer. He just create a new account each time.

Is this allowed? I think somebody should merge those accounts and explain him how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to unregistered accounts.  If you don't remember the password, and you clear your cookies, you can just continually create new accounts.

Comment: Isn't that what account recovery e-mails are for?

Comment: Ok, but we have 4 accounts in 5 days. I heavily doubt he just forgot his password.

Comment: I've found another one... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204175/exp-boost-question this one isn't tied to the account @Robotnik linked below.

Comment: @shanodin - Thanks, seems like a new one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible s/he's browsing in private-mode, meaning that once the browser is closed, all cookies are erased. It's not necessarily malice or ill-will.

**Update:** The 9 or so accounts seem to have now been merged into [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/99025/amo-shah).